# Transforming excel index to pandas index

Tags: python, pandas

To give a bit of backstory, I created and excel sheet that transforms the excel column index to pandas index. Which in essense is just a simple Vlookup, on a defined table e.g Column A=0, Column B=1. It gets the job done, however it's not as efficient as I would like it to be.

I use these index on my function to rename those fields to follow our current nomenclature. e.g

```
df = df.rename(columns={df.columns[5]: "Original Claim Type",
                        df.columns [1]:"Date of Loss",
                        df.columns[3]:"Date Reported (tpa)",
                        df.columns[2]:"Employer Report Date",
                        df.columns[4]:"Original Status",
                        df.columns[6]:"Date Closed",
                        df.columns[27]:"(net)Total Paid",
                        df.columns[23]:"(net) Total Incurred",
                        df.columns[25]:"NET Paid(Med)",
                        df.columns[26]:"NET Paid(Exp)",
                        df.columns[24]:"NET Paid (Ind)",
                        df.columns[18]:"Original Litigation",
                        df.columns[7]:"Date of Hire",
                        df.columns[8]:"Date of Birth",
                        df.columns[9]:"Benefit State",
                        df.columns[15]:"Original Cause",
                        df.columns[17]:"Body Part",
                        df.columns[32]:"TTD Days"})
```

My new solution was to create a Dictionairy that maps the values, and their corresponding index.

[image: The image is a snippet of the excel file, so I list the column header where it can be found on the file, and the vlookup formula gives the corresponding python index (It takes into account that pandas index starts at 0, thus subtracting all values by 1)]

```
excel_index={'A':0,'B':1,'C':2}
test={"Claim Number":[0,1,2,3,4,5]}
test=pd.DataFrame(test)
test=test.rename(columns={ test.columns[excel_index['A']]: "Frog"})
```

It works, however the only problem I have is that I would have to manually type out all the index values beforehand.

What would be a more efficient way to carry this out?

-Brandon

Comment: could you show an example of what your data looks like in excel, and what you want it to look like in pandas? If you have a row of column names in excel, you can specify that upon import to pandas.

Comment: Sure thing, I updated a snippet.

Comment: unless I am not understanding your request, the answer below should work.

Comment: Negative, what i'm trying to do is transform Excels column index e.g [A,B,C,D,E,F,G] to Pandas respective index [0,1,2,3,4,5,6] in order be used in my renaming formula.

Comment: `index_col=0` would make the index here A B C D... I guess I'm not really understanding your request

Comment: Appreciate the effort though.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a column of index names, such as the on in your example, you can specify that in the pd.read_excel command. Since your index column is 5, it would read like this:

```
df = pd.read_excel('yourfilename.xlsx', index_col=5)
```